# Will msync incur cost for unchanged memory?

Tags: mmap

Suppose I have a `mmap`'d file that is sized 100mb. I then changed a value at the first 8 bytes and the last 8 bytes.

And I then call msync on the whole segment, instead of two msync calls.

Will the kernel flush all the memory in between as well, or is the kernel smart enough to just handle the first and last segments of the memory? What if there's hundreds of these small segments?

I've been wondering whether I should make my own memory change tracker so I can pool up `msync` calls, or is that worrying too much about nothing? I'm just worried that too many of these will block for too long, especially as I'm doing this just before doing `munmap`, hence I can't rely on async version of `msync`, since apparently "there is no guarantee that changes are written back before `munmap`(2) is called".

But if the kernel is smart enough, I guess just calling `msync` on the whole memory segment would work and I can call it a day, but I wasn't able to find info from a cursory search on this topic (my google-fu is failing me).

Answer (score 1):

Found the answer - from a kernel discussion in 2012: https://lwn.net/Articles/502612/

> `msync`() takes two parameters indicating the offset and length of the
> memory area to be written back. But the kernel has always ignored
> those parameters, choosing instead to just write back all modified
> pages in the file, and the related metadata as well.

So I guess tracking areas that were changed is unnecessary complexity.

Comment: so do this means, kernel will only write the changed memory and not the entire file ?